# css - padding propagating to next column

Tags: css

I have this basic HTML structure:

```
<div id="left-column"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="right-column"></div>
```

And this css:

```
#left-column
{
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 80px;
    background: url('../../common/images/black70.png');
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#content
{
    padding: 5px;
}

#right-column
{
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 190px;
    background: url('../../common/images/black40.png');
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

The problem is content padding is being propagated to right column:

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `#right-column` is after `#content` so in the document flow, it will start after the content, which has `10px` height from its top and bottom padding.

If you re-order your HTML like so, it fixes your issue.

```
<div id="left-column"></div>
<div id="right-column"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YzXV/)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got floating things and non-floating things, the floating things should always come before the non-floating ones in the source.

In your case, the content is rendered first, and then the right-column below that.